# How to Win Friends and Influence People

Tags: word-choice

The title of the best seller book from Dale Carnegie uses the word "win" in an odd way to me. The most common usage would be "How to Make Friends and Influence People", wouldn't it?

Comment: Carnegie's target audience is people who aspire to be ***winners*** (in the game of life), so in context ***win*** is an appropriate verb.

Comment: Consider the word [winsome](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/winsome), which may have some bearing on this particular use of *win*.

Comment: Literally the first meaning of *[win](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/win)* in MW is *win. 1a. to get possession of by effort or fortune. b. to obtain by work.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's just using a different meaning *win*, where it refers to acquiring or gaining something as a result of a contest, like winning a prize. You might win a race in order to win a prize, but the prize is the only thing you take home with you.

In the context of Carnegie's book, making friends is treated as a challenge you take on for personal gain. The usage here is more like that in winning favour, or winning affection. Through the techniques the book teaches you, you will win people over as your friends.

Comment: Exactly. This is a metaphor, and the [metaphor theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) appears to be something like Friendship is a Prize in a Contest. The details of the contest, or game, being played, and of its participants, are open to contextual intrepretation (or, usually, ignored in an idiom like _win friendship_).